# Вставить переменную в get запрос

Tags: javascript, get

Нужно передать значение переменной. Что я делаю не так?

```
  <script>
  var number = 5;
  location = "?number";
  </script>  

  В итоге получается http://site.ru?number, а нужно сделать http://site.ru?5
```

Comment: `location = "?" + number;`

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае стоит использовать это:
[`location.search = 5`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/location)